# how to force angular to re-bind/update even there is no change in the model

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

Ok -- so you might be thinking why would you want this but I am trying to render some HTML using ng-html-bind like so (in HAML):

```
#my-visualization-panel{'ng-bind-html' => 'htmlSource'}
```

the htmlSource has some html which renders a visualization using c3.js visualization library. The `htmlSource` looks something like this

```
<script>
  var MY_DATA = localStorage.getItem('MY_DATA');
  c3.generate({
    data: {
      columns: MY_DATA
    }
 });
</script>
```

So the problem is that I update the visualization by re-setting `localStorage['MY_DATA']`. However, while the data that `MY_DATA` refers to might change, the actual `htmlSource` does not, so the view fails to update.

Is there a way to force the view to update even if the model, ostensibly, does not?

Comment: what's the point of using `ng-bind-html` at all in this instance? the appropriate way to deal with non-angular scripts in an angular context is to wrap them in a directive.

Comment: The bigger context is to allow a user to write their own c3.js code and see it visualized on the page. So need `ng-bind-html` to display and render dynamically generated html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend changing the HTML anyway. For example

```
<script>
  var MY_DATA = localStorage.getItem('MY_DATA');// 2482486284968248968 (hash of my_data, guid, or serial number)
  c3.generate({
    data: {
      columns: MY_DATA
    }
 });
</script>
```

This will allow your script to operate as you expect, directly, without having to do big sweeping updates or hacks. Even if you "force a refresh", if the HTML doesn't change, Angular will not re-execute your script.

Another possibility is to call `localStorage.getItem('MY_DATA')` in your angular controllers / directives, instead of indirectly hoping Angular will run it for you via HTML updates. That seems to be the kind of control you're looking for.

Comment: perhaps I don't understand the problem exactly, but your code looks exactly like the code that was posted in the question?

Comment: I added a comment to the script with a key that will change along with `MY_DATA`. OP's problem is that his HTML doesn't change. This is a way to make it change.

Comment: @tenfour added a comment into the html, which will trigger angular update -- which is my workaround but I am not a big fan of it; I just can't believe there isn't a better way in angular

Comment: Angular's binding is for updating HTML. But what you're trying to do is run script every time `MY_DATA` changes. That's why I suggest you run `localStorage.getItem('MY_DATA')` in your model or controller then when it changes. I am guessing you have code to explicitly generate `MY_DATA` so this should be an option. Or, have Angular bind directly to `MY_DATA`.

Comment: yea, I do exactly that. The actual object `MY_DATA` refers to will be correct and non-stale. For example, `console.log(localStorage.getItem('MY_DATA'))` returns exactly what I want and expect. The issue is purely the binding between `htmlSource` and the view.

Comment: Also, if there were a way to bind to `MY_DATA` w/r/t to the detect changes portion of the data binding, but display `htmlSource`, it would be ideal -- but I have not been able to find how to do that in angular.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `apply` method of the [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) object:

```
$scope.apply();
```

if you are still getting the digest in progress errors, you can also make use of the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) object that will run the function in the next digest cycle:

```
$timeout(function() {
    //code
});
```

as per your latest comment in this answer it seems to be that you are looking for the [$scope.watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) method. You can add a watcher in order to listen when something changes.

Comment: hm, the problem is that the digest cycle is happening correctly -- so I get  $apply already in progress errors when I use `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()`

Comment: I've added the $timeout approach.

Comment: Generally, the answer I feel like I am groping for isn't how to trigger the digest cycle but to change how angular detects if something has changed. Like if there is some way to over-write its normal behavior (which is simply to call angular.equals on the model). Another digest cycle would go through all the watchers and simply return with the same answer which is that the model hasn't changed.

Comment: now I've added the watch method maybe it's what you ate looking for. :)

Comment: `$scope.apply()` is not an AngularJS function, use `$scope.$apply()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent around 2-3 hours to resolve this issue. Finally I found solution

```
$scope.$apply();
```